# Error: The section VersionOverrides 1.0 of the manifest is not valid. A Child node of the node VersionOverrides named webapplicationinfo is not valid

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, exchange-server-2016

I have an outlook addin working as expected on all platforms except the following.

- Outlook 2016 (16.0.5257.1000) MSO (16.0.5366.1000) 64 bits
- Exchange server 15.1 build 1713.5

When I try to install the addin - I get the error below

**Error: The section VersionOverrides 1.0 of the manifest is not valid. A Child node of the node VersionOverrides named webapplicationinfo is not valid.**

My maniest does contain the webapplicationinfo node which is a part of VersionOverridesV1_0 as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/versionoverrides-1-0-content?view=outlook-js-1.3)

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Do you deploy the add-in via Exchange or just sideload in Outlook? Where do you get such error?

Comment: I receive the error when I try to sideload the addin on this specific outlook client

Comment: Could you post the exact manifest file you use for that? You may edit the IDs, but it would be great to see how it looks like.

Comment: Sure - manifest can be seen here https://pastebin.com/raw/1eUnV3w4

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the host application doesn't support the [Identity API 1.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/identity-api-requirement-sets?view=powerpoint-js-preview) requirement set required for SSO (see the `WebApplicationInfo` element).

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the same addin on HostApplications that does support IdentityAPI1.3 but I was able to install with no issue - I infact have some logic in the taskpane to check if IdentityAPI1.3 is supported and present a different authentication flow.

Comment: Your Outlook may not know anything about the `WebApplicationInfo` element in the manifest.

Comment: Eugene is correct. Note that the reference topic for [`<WebApplicationInfo>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/webapplicationinfo?view=powerpoint-js-preview) says that it is associated with Identity API 1.3. The latter is not supported on Outlook 2016 (16.0.5257.1000, as the article that Eugene linked to shows.